# Stereo capture with v4l2

Tags: video, c++

I am trying to capture images from 2 cameras using the driver v4l2.
I want to capture them at the same time so I use threads with conditions to start the capture at the same time. The problem is that the capture is always slower for the second device (I tried with different cameras and inverting them).

I modified a little bit this [example](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) for the capture.

I use [this camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minoru_3D_Webcam) (both camera), but I also tried with one camera from minoru and a common webcam (in 640*480 at 15 fps)

Here is the output of my program:

```
Signal
/dev/video1 debut: 00:00:00.637.043
/dev/video0 debut: 00:00:00.637.157
/dev/video1 fin: 00:00:00.637.645
/dev/video0 fin: 00:00:00.700.939
Signal
/dev/video1 debut: 00:00:00.701.104
/dev/video0 debut: 00:00:00.701.163
/dev/video1 fin: 00:00:00.704.868
/dev/video0 fin: 00:00:00.768.935
Signal
/dev/video1 debut: 00:00:00.769.024
/dev/video0 debut: 00:00:00.769.138
/dev/video1 fin: 00:00:00.769.627
/dev/video0 fin: 00:00:00.836.922
```

So I don't understand why the first capture is really fast and the second one is not.
Any idea or recommandations ? Could this come from the v4l2 drivers ?

Comment: Did you turned on compression? I think bandwith is too big to have simultaneous transmission. Also see this project: http://code.google.com/p/libv4l2cam/ . It supports Minoru. I think the easiest way to get two images is to use gstreamer with appsink and ignore v4l2 completely.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I did not know about compression and just saw the Compression Parameters- VIDIOC_G_COMP, VIDIOC_S_COMP. I will give it a try and post my results ! As for libv4l2cam, I already looked at it, and I am actually using some of the code (e.g. for the calibration) but they have the same problem with their code...

Comment: By how many ms is the second camera slower and is it always deterministic? I have a same problem with OpenCV and 2 Microsoft USB webcams (LiveCam Studio) - the sync degree is not deterministic (changes in time) and varies greatly in free run from say less than 16ms (could not test better on 60Hz LCD) up to few tenths or even hundred of ms. OpenCV just runs on top of v4l2 so I think the cause is the same as yours. I would be very much like to learn the cause... Would you provide your code (that altered example) so that I could test it quickly?